# No automatic update of my launcher app

Tags: android, google-play, android-launcher

I make an Android launcher app and I published this app in the store.
The problem is it seem the people don't receive the update of the app automatically...
They have to go to the store and click to the update button.

It's the same when Sync is enabled in settings & background Data is not restricted.

Maybe because it's a launcher and the Google Play Store doesn't update the app who are being used (to not reload it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play can take upto 24 hours to push application updates across all its servers.

Just wait for a while, and all your eligible users should receive the update. However, if your update adds feature requests that some devices don't support, they will not get the update. And one more thing you must make sure that the app u have installed in ur mobile is not apk built with debug keystore.. the play store will show always as "Open" button instead of "Update" if the play store app certificate doesn't match with installed app certificate. I realized this when i did trial and error with debug and signed apk's. Only signed apk worked. And use versionCode for comparing versions instead of version Name.